# re matching "optional" arguments

Tags: regex

This question is about regexp matching.  Suppose I have a string that can take on one of three forms:

```
s1 = "id";
s2 = "id, title";
s3 = "id, title, date";
```

I'd like to concoct a regular expression that would extract the id, title and date fields of the string (if provided).

Using JavaScript like syntax, the following regex matches all three strings by making all but the first `, xxxx` field optional using the ? operator.  It works, but it's kind of cumbersome:

```
const regex = /(\w+)(?:\s*,\s*(\w+))?(?:\s*,\s*(\w+))?/;
const s1 = 'id';
const s3 = 'id, title';
const s3 = 'id, title, date';
```

Is there a more straightforward way to do the same thing?

Comment: `input.split(", ");`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
re_p = r"(\w+)(?:, *(\w+))?(?:, *(\w+))?"
```

See here for results: [Click Here](https://regex101.com/r/SUueVA/1/)

Comment: You get the checkmark for a correct answer (and points for the example) -- thank you.  But truth be told, I'm going to take https://stackoverflow.com/users/8967612/ahmed-abdelhameed 's suggestion of using `.split()`

Comment: Yes, split is easier.